# Google Apps Admin SDK getting gmail storage space used

Tags: gmail, google-admin-sdk

I would like to retrieve a users "Mail Storage Used" value from the ADMIN SDK for my google apps account.

I have looked all over for how to get this value and can not find it anywhere.

It seems like it would be here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail

But it is not.  Does anyone know how I can get space used from Gmail for a google apps account?

Google does this on their own console as shown below?  How do I do this through their API?

[image: Screenshot from google apps console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of unified storage (you can read more about it here: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-for-google.html), the quota value in gmail is actually being deprecated.  This information is highlighted on the yellow banner of the Google Apps Reporting API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/).

So how can you retrieve the quota usage of your account now that only one quota is being applied across three products? You will look up your quota usage using the Drive SDK (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) instad.  This will give you an idea of how much quota you have used.

Comment: This would obviously be the preferred way and I was actually able to do this, the issue is that it gives you the quota for the currently logged in user, I can't find a way to get the quota for say all of my users in google apps.  For example if I want to make a report of which users are using the most space in the organization.

Comment: The usage_in_bytes field of the old Accounts report may meet your needs until Google updates the new Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/#accounts_report It's unclear if the field indicates just Gmail or agregate usage for accounts with unified storage, you should do some tests to determine for yourself.

Comment: Can do I will give this a go thanks! If indeed it works I will come back and mark as answered.  I hope the fact that it got deprecated doesn't come back to haunt me.  This seems like something that would be a fairly common request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was there at one point but they pulled it when Google switched to unified storage between Gmail and Drive. One way to determine the account quota would be to connect via [IMAP using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview) and issue the IMAP quota command.

Comment: The issue I am having here is that the use case is as a google apps admin I want to be able to see all of the space being used by my users.  Accessing IMAP via OATH would require me to log in as each user, I am looking more for a report an admin would run.